# Backpage image field upload image to s3 where path is based on the id of the entity created

Tags: laravel, image, amazon-s3, crud, laravel-backpack

How can I upload an image to s3 utilizing laravel backpack's CRUD controller where the path is based on the id of the entity that is about to be saved into the database?? For example I need it to be saved to `Users/{user_id}/20_random_characters.file_type`

Included below is a set of working code where the user's avatar will be uploaded into AWS S3 Bucket under the file directory of `Tests/20_random_characters.file_type`. How can I get it to be saved in a directory with the `{user_id}` instead if at the point of creating the image field the user entity is yet to exist as it hasn't saved into the database yet?

```
UserCrudController

protected function store(){

    Log::info("Within Store Function");
    $requestData = $this->crud->getRequest()->all();

    $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('create');
    // Sets Validation Rules
    $this->crud->setValidation(StoreRequest::class);
    // Executes Validation ( Code is killed here if validation fails )
    $this->crud->validateRequest();

    $this->crud->unsetValidation();
    
    // Validation successful
    $response = $this->traitStore();

    return $response; // Return response from traitStore

}    

protected function setupCreateOperation(){
   $this->populateFields();

   Widget::add()->type('script')->content(asset('asset/user.js'));
}

protected function populateFields(){
    CRUD::field([
        'name'      => 'avatar',
        'label'     => 'Avatar',
        'type'      => 'image', // Image / Upload
        'withFiles' => [
            'disk' => 's3', // the disk where the file will be stored
            // Dynamic path based on user_id
            'path' => 'Tests', // the path inside the disk where the file will be stored
            'fileNamer' => function ($file, $data) { 
                // $file => encoded base 64 format of the uploaded image
                
                // Generate a unique filename
                $fileNameGenerator = new StandardFileNameGenerator; // Instantiate the class
                
                return $fileNameGenerator->getName($file);
            },
            // 'fileNamer' => \App\Library\Uploaders\StandardFileNameGenerator::class
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the logged user id, you can use: backpack_user()['id']

Could you try to add this to your path and check if works as you need?

Check these Helpers on our [documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/base-about#helpers-1).

Cheers.

Comment: Appreciate the response but what i need is the id of the record being created and not the id of the logged in user